# pynput attribute error "key" object has no attribute "char"

Tags: python, pynput

I'm using this keyboard listener thread:

```
listener = keyboard.Listener(
  on_press=on_press,
  on_release=on_release)
listener.start()
```

Heres how my `on_press()` & `on_release()` functions:

```
def on_press(key):
  if key.char == (A1_bind):
    A1.config(bg=pad_active, fg=pad_active)
    banklights.itemconfig(bank_a_light, fill=banklight_active)
    print("Pad A1 Triggered")
```

```
def on_release(key):
  if key.char == (A1_bind):
    A1.config(bg=pad, fg=pad)
    banklights.itemconfig(bank_a_light, fill=banklight)
```

Heres my error message when I press keys like `ctrl`, `alt`, `tab` etc:

```
AttributeError: 'Key' object has no attribute 'char'
```

Please help me to fix this so when one of those keys listed above do not trigger this error.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because key is not the same object depending if the key pressed was a character or a special key (like ctrl or f11). If it was a apecial key, it would not have a char attribute. I don't know the details of this, maybe someone else can explain.

Putting your if statement in a try and except block should help, something like this :

```
def on_press(key):
    try:
        if key.char == (A1_bind):
            A1.config(bg=pad_active, fg=pad_active)
            banklights.itemconfig(bank_a_light, fill=banklight_active)
            print("Pad A1 Triggered")
    except:
        #do something else
```